# Magento 2 Check a customer attribute is changed during save

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, save

I have created user Approve module which lets admin to approve user after registration.

I want to send a email on activation and deactivation of a user, How can I find that the admin has changed the status during save.

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `getOrigData` to check it :

Example :

```
$customerData = $observer->getEvent()->getData('customer');
$newData = $customerData->getData('test');
$previousData = $customerData->getOrigData('test');
```

And then you can compare :

```
$previousData == $newData ? echo 'same' : echo 'different';
```